# How can I use my $mysqli object inside my class if it's declared outside of scope?

Tags: php, oop, class, scope, mysqli

I just started doing OOP, so I apologize in advance if there is a simple solution.
Basically I need to use my **$mysqli** object inside a *class*. I've seperated it into two files.

**config2.php**

```
class Config
{

    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $username = '****';
    public $password = '****';
    public $database = '****';

    function report_error($query)
    {
        $email = '*@hotmail.com';
        $subject = 'MySQL error.';
        $message = "IP: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} \n URL: http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']} \n\n MySQL query: {$query} \n\n MySQL error: " . $mysqli->error();

        mail($email, $subject, $message);
        die('Oops, an error has occured. The administrator has been notified.');
    }

}

$config = new Config();
$mysqli = new mysqli($config->host, $config->username, $config->password, $config->database);

if($mysqli->connect_error)
    report_error($mysqli);
```

**administration.php**

```
require('includes/config2.php');

$mysqli->real_escape_string();   // Works out of scope.

class Account
{
    public $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string();   // Doesn't work in scope.
    public $password;

    function login()
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help guys, I appreciate it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the object to the constructor of `Account` and save it as a private instance variable.

`Account` is directly dependent on an instance of `mysqli`, so there is nothing wrong with making that clear by specifying it as a required parameter in the constructor. That is the only way you can make sure that whenever `Account` is used the mysqli object is there too. If you access it from a global state instead (by either having a static accessor or by directly accessing the global scope) you can never guarantee that it is really there.

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate the $mysqli object and make it [static](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.static.php)

usually you would encapsulate the DB in some class called "DBConnection" or similar. And this instance should manage the real $mysqli object as [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

in (very)short:

```
class Config
{
    public $host = 'localhost';
    [...]
    public static  $connectionObj 
    public static getConnection(){
      if (!isset($this->connectionObj ){
        $connectionObj = new mysqli($this->host, $config->this, $config->this, $this->database);
        if($mysqli->connect_error){
          report_error($mysqli);
        }
      }
      return $this->connectionObj;
    }
}
```

You get access to this object from everywhere:

```
$mysqlObj = Config.getConnection()
```

**DISCLAIMER:** 
This is very short, untested code and database should not went into config class but its own database class with all SQL functions as methods, this is just for reusing your provided code